# Chose implementation of the view controller of my non anemic domain model

Tags: model-view-controller, oop, design-patterns, model

The title might not be easy to understand but it seems to me it is a basic design question when dealing with smart models.

I have a hierarchy of model objects that represent different types of document.
Say I have a view with different buttons, each one opens the document of the underlying object model. When I click on a button I have to display a view whose controller implementation depends only on the underlying model object class. How do I get this implementation ?
(It could be in the implementation of the button but then the question becomes how do I get the implementation of the button)

Should it be a factory that takes as an input the type of my model and returns my view controller ? Should it be my model that knows how to build its controller (seems dirty nè ?) ? Should I use composition ? Something else ?

I hope I am being clear enough. I am a bit struggling with this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too abstract to give a specific advice. MVC pattern appears in many forms and in many technologies. For a web page it will have one shape, for a WPF app it will have another. In general there are both "view-first" and "controller-first" approaches. You can start with any one and see if it comes natural for your problem, if not -- refactor.

One other area you can explore is the area of modern composite application frameworks which provide out-of-the-box modular MVC\MVVM solutions. If you're writing for web, read about ASP.NET MVC and its best practices. If you're writing for WPF, read about MVVM approach and take a look at [Prism](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/mtaulty/prism--silverlight-part-1-taking-sketched-code-towards-unity), for example. You might find that your problem is already solved by existing tools.